# Technical debt ratio sonar decimal

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1, technical-debt

I am using Sonarqube version 5.1 and saw that the technical debt ratio percentage shows very little or no variation for the monthly reports that we generate. It is seen that the value is rounded off to only one decimal point and so the variation is not identified. Is there any setting by which we can increase the number of decimal points in technical debt ratio.

Answer (score 0):

There is no setting to change precision of float measures as of now. There is a ticket associated to SonarQube 5.3 to cover this use case: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6939

Comment: Thanks for the information Alexandre. Is there an option in manual metrics where we can write a formula to calculate the required technical debt as a float value where it would show more precision.